# How to make loop on var option

Tags: c#, iteration

I have this code

```
var result = from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
             group row by row.Field<string>("Campaign") into grp
             select new
             {
                 Campaign = grp.Key,
                 Count = grp.Count(),
                 SL = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<Decimal>("Inb.ServiceLevel"))
             };
```

Where the `DTgraph` is a `DataTable`

I want to make loop on `result`. How please?

Comment: [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

Comment: @TomTom that code returns many rows. so there is no specific type to loop on. I mean I can't make this `foreach (int element in fibarray)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    //Your code here
}
```

Or `for` to know the index. But you have to add `.ToList()` at the end of your LINQ:

```
var result = (from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
             group row by row.Field<string>("Campaign") into grp
             select new
             {
                 Campaign = grp.Key,
                 Count = grp.Count(),
                 SL = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<Decimal>("Inb.ServiceLevel"))
             }).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
{
    //Your code here
    //Now you can do result[i].Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a loop:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
   //your logic to each item of loop
}
```

Comment: how to know the index of the `item` ? should I make outside variable and keep update it in each time ?